# Trying to learn about core concepts in Javascript by making a web app, how can I do that without jumping to MVC frameworks?

Tags: javascript

For some reason I don't want to jump to a javascript MVC framework to make a web app for my portfolio. My main motive behind that is to learn in & outs of Javascript. What are my options if I want to make a web app without using MVC? Keep in mind, I still know basic concepts but I want to dig deeper into Javascript.

Comment: Is there something specific you want to do that can't be done with javascript?

Comment: Not really, I know the limitations of javascript but there are still some concepts that I feel I don't know yet so I thought it would be better if I start using them practically.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the big JavaScript frameworks tend to include the following features:

1. Ajax API
2. Event manager/listeners
3. Promises
4. Class system
5. DOM widgets
6. Templating

My recommendation is to study and implement each of these concepts. As you work through them, you'll find that most of them tie together on some fundamental level. Ajax and Promises work well together, so do templating and DOM widgets, DOM widgets and event managers, etc. Once you understand these concepts and how they work together, you'll see that there's nothing special about MVC/MVVM frameworks. It's all just JavaScript.

You'll also learn quite a bit about JavaScript in general as certain components tend to emphasize certain parts of the language. Implementing a class system will give you a deep understanding of JavaScript's prototypes, Promises will open your mind to new model of asynchronous programming, templates will test your string manipulation and regular expression skills, and so forth.

You're already on the right track. Making a web app using an MVC framework only proves that you can use that one framework. By understanding the core components, you should be able to pick up and adapt to any framework future employers are using.

Comment: Most of the concepts you mentioned, surprising I haven't even touched them. So I would definitely try to touch each one of them. Sometimes it seems like it's a lot but I guess I need to have a lot of patience.